# how to disable RIGHT CLICK in summernote text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, summernote

I want to custom drop-down list in summernote text editor on right click.so how can achieve this.
I created some sample but right click event is not disabling in summernote text editor.and contextmenu not working it.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.oncontextmenu = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.